# angular JS filter column by column

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, filter

[image]

Hi all how to filter this picture in columns top inputs column by column?

Thanks all.

Comment: Did you try anything? take a look at the ng docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/21091/)

```
  <input ng-model="search.name"/>
  <input ng-model="search.age"/>
  <input ng-model="search.gender"/>  
  <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in todos | filter:search">
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.age}}</td>
    <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```